# Fill offset between two lines/polygons

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile of the property limits of one site. I'm trying to create a 10m line offset from this line, and fill/hash the gap beetween them. What would be the process?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based off the assumption that your shapefile of the property limits is a polygon and not a line.

---

**If you just want to show this as symbology** then you can set the property boundary layer's symbology type to Geometry Generator and use this expression:

`difference(buffer($geometry, 10, 10), $geometry)`

If this is what your property boundary looks like beforehand:
[image]

Then this is what it will look like using that expression in a Geometry Generator:

[image]

Then to change it to a hashed fill just change the sub-symbology Simple Fill to a Line Pattern Fill and have at it. You can also add another sub-symbology as an Outline: Simple Line to add the outline, like this:

[image]

---

**If you want this to exist as a new data layer** then you can use the processing tool "Geometry by expression" located in the Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry.

Just use the property boundary layer as the input layer and use the same expression as above:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: what should I do if I need the 10m offset to be inside of the limit polygon and not outside ?

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to do it by converting the polygon to line, offsetting it -10m, convert back to polygon and apply the geometry formulta :) thanks again !